# Falcon 9: Landing leg helium pressure?

Tags: launch, falcon-9, vertical-landing, helium, legs

So it seems the Falcon 9 landing legs are powered by a helium precharge.

Does anyone know the pressure of that precharge? If no numbers for Falcon 9, is there at least a reasonable range of what the pressure might be?

Comment: 200 or 300 bar is a standard pressure for gaseous helium tanks. There are valves designed for this pressure.

Comment: Thanks, Uwe! So 3,000-4,000 psi. Wow that's a generous amount of pressure for the legs.

Comment: Normally in these pneumatic systems the tank pressure gets regulated down to a working pressure. In the shuttle orbiter the regulator outlet pressure was ~750 psi, they also had ~3000 psi tanks.